# position bottom next just below 2 div with absolute position

Tags: css, position

How to position a `bottom 0` div just after 2 div with both div having position absolute using css.

I want the blue div to appear just below the black border. In my current demo the border and blue are overlapping just like in my project. How to make them not to overlap

```css
.footer {
  /*position: fixed;*/
  display: block;
  position: ;
  /*position:absolute;*/
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #2f4296;
  border-top: solid 1px #4443af;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.flip {
  /backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  font: normal 14px helvetica, arial, san serif;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  transition: all 3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  font: normal 14px helvetica, arial, san serif;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  -ms-transition: all 3s;
  -o-transition: all 3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="flip"></div>
<div class="flip"></div>

<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: is it possible to use floats instead of position absolute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the `position:absolute` removes the elements from its normal flow on the page.

You can try something like this

HTML

```
<div class="flip-container">
<div class="flip"></div>
<div class="flip"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
.footer {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #2f4296;
  border-top: solid 1px #4443af;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.flip-container{
  position: relative;
  height:90vh;
}

.flip {
  /backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  font: normal 14px helvetica, arial, san serif;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  transition: all 3s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  font: normal 14px helvetica, arial, san serif;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px;
  transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  -ms-transition: all 3s;
  -o-transition: all 3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
}
```

[Link for reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/b4y57yv6/1/)

Hope this Helps..

Comment: what does `90vh` in css for height

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height:50vh;
}
.footer {
  display: block;
  position: ;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #2f4296;
  border-top: solid 1px #4443af;
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;
}
.flip {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-width:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flip"></div>
  <div class="flip"></div>

  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: waht does `height:50vh;` mean